# MongoDB cannot insert document because it exceeds 180 levels of nesting

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, nested, reduce

I'm new to MongoDB and I would really appreciate your help.

I'm trying to do a map/reduce, using MongoDB's java driver 3.4.2.

I have a collection collectionA which has documents such as this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a29a6757c5def07307a4b6f"),
    "someProperty1" : "454545",
    "someProperty2" : "1234",
    "myArray" : [ 
        "1", 
        "2", 
        "3", 
    ]
}
```

I would like to get all the combinations of myArray: [1,2] [1,3] [2,1] [2,3] [3,1] [3,2]

The longest myArray has 20 elements.

I've tried using the following:

```
db.collectionA.mapReduce(
    function () {
        var elem= this;
        this.myArray.forEach(function (parent) {
            elem.myArray.forEach(function (child) {
                if (parent !== child)
                    emit(parent, child);
                });
        });
    },

    function (key, values) {
        return {
            result: Array.from(new Set(values))
        };
    },
    {
        query: {
            $where: "this.myArray.length > 1"
        },
        out: "collectionB"
    });
```

It worked fine when I tested it with a small amount of data. Problem is now I have 21.5 million documents in the source collection, and it's throwing this exception.

> Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-5"
>   com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 15:
>   '**cannot insert document because it exceeds 180 levels of nesting**' on
>   server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" :
>   "cannot insert document because it exceeds 180 levels of nesting",
>   "code" : 15, "codeName" : "Overflow" }    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:115)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:114)
>     at

What am I doing wrong? what would be the correct way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out I had a misconception about the way the reduce function works. It had been working fine with small amounts of data by mere luck (or back luck, really). I changed the map function to emit emit(parent, {result:[child]});
And the reduce function to:

```
function (key, values) {
    resultSet = new Set();
    values.forEach(function (partialResult) {
        partialResult.result.forEach(function (elem) {
            resultSet.add(elem);
        });
    });
    return {
        result: Array.from(resultSet)
    };
}
```

works like a charm.